# Can we slowdown speed of photons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, mass, speed-of-light, refraction

Can we slowdown speed of photons or light? If we slowdown the speed of photon can photon give us mass?

Comment: What do you mean give us mass, do you mean the photon gains mass?

Answer (score 2):

The photon is a type of elementary particle. It is the quantum of the electromagnetic field including electromagnetic radiation such as light and radio waves and the force carrier for the electromagnetic force. Photons are massless, so they always move at the speed of light in a vacuum, $299792458$ m/s (or about $186,282$ mi/s).

---

Recall that $$\mathbf{p}=\gamma m_0\mathbf{u}$$If we consider the limit $m_0\rightarrow 0$ while $u\rightarrow c$, then $\mathbf{p}$ can remain finite. Evidently, a particle without mass can carry momentum, provided that it travels at the speed of light.

---

> Can we slow down the speed of photons or light?

This is a simple No! As we have show massless particles can only travel at the speed of light.

Comment: Photon are massless in speed of light but what if we slow down it and it give us mass. Photons energy is converted into mass by einstein equation E=mc2

Comment: Photons are mastless particles and I have proved that they can only move with the speed of light then How you go about slowing them down. Beside this ,$E=mc^2$ is not for photon particles.

Comment: Check this link (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/01/150123144158.htm&ved=2ahUKEwjBjo76pt3tAhVRXsAKHfydCJEQFjAEegQIJhAE&usg=AOvVaw2d-OKlsLDULKFfnpuos2wA) photon can be slow down in water and also in free space